# What does Ctrl+S+S do on Xamarin Android .axml files in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is my original **.axml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ListView android:id="@+id/List"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

I was saving it and hit `Ctrl+S` as per usual, but then I hit `S` again accidentally without letting go of `Ctrl`, so effectively I hit `Ctrl+S+S`. This resulted in the code formatted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that this is different again to the `Ctrl+E+D` shortcut which I am used to, which results in code formatted differently as per the below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/List"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is ... what exactly did I do? What feature or macro did I accidentally invoke? I have tested this key combination on a normal **.cs** file and also a **.xml** file, and this keyboard combination doesn't do anything there. I had a quick look at **Tools -> Options -> Keyboard** but there is too much noise and I can't filter it sensibly (to my knowledge). In any case, I hadn't previously changed anything there in this VS instance, and nor do I have anything like ReSharper installed.

Comment: TeamTam, this made me laugh - stackoverflow fixed both of your code snippets to look the same! I can see from trying to edit your post that the code you pasted in is different, but Stackoverflow isn't having any of that today. You might want to edit your code differently to show the problem!

Comment: Hey @AlexK ... it looks ok to me? Do you mean the 2nd & 3rd blocks look the same to you? If so, there is a subtle difference. In the 2nd block, Ctrl+S+S indented the 'ListView' tag at 4 spaces, whereas in the 3rd block, Ctrl+E+D indented the 'ListView' tag at 2 space.

Comment: Oh! My bad. I just noticed that. Very weird. Try it with a bigger block of code - there are probably bigger differences between the two methods of indenting.

Comment: I noticed this too. In particular, if somebody can enlighten us on this feature, I would like to know how I can disable it or change the formatting rules that are applied when hitting `Ctrl+S+S`.